# Rails : How to create more than one form with a submit button, doing different functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, form-submit

I want to create more than one form with a submit button, with each submit button having a different action/functionalities to perform.
 How to achieve this?  For now all the submit buttons takes the create controller method as its action function. How to override this ?.  Can I give name to each submit button and redirect each button's action to different method in its controller file?
  How to do it ?    I'm using rail 3.0.1.

Comment: To clarify: do you have multiple forms with submit buttons in each form? Or do you have one form with multiple submit buttons inside?

Comment: Hmmm, my case is multiple forms in the same model with submit buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the form_for helper method, I believe it uses the new_record? method on whatever object you're passing it to determine the proper action it should point to. For example:

```
<%= form_for @page do |f| %>
```

If @page.new_record? evaluates to true, the form will POST to the create method on the PagesController. However, if it evaluates to false, it will POST to the update method on the PagesController.

You can override the URL the form POSTs to by doing something like:

```
<%= form_for @page, :url => { :action => "my_action" } do |f| %>
```

That will allow you to send the form data to a custom action. You don't have to change anything related to the submit buttons.

Hope that helps!